# Edit files with with VSCode Remote-SSH extension that require root permissions

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm using VSCode Remote-SSH extension and I connect with SSH to my Amazon Linux 2 instance. I can connect to folders on my AL2 with ec2-user permissions, but can write to files only with root permissions. While trying to write to files i get a message "Failed to save 'PostsControler.php' :Unable to write file. (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permissio denied.
I connect to server with next settings:

```
Host 192.168.1.178
   HostName 192.168.1.178
   Port 22
   User ec2-user
```